# "Fermentor" vs. "fermenter"

Tags: word-choice, differences, orthography, agent-noun-suffix

I am curious to know the correct usage of these words as it seems to be misused often. See https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/59 for a related question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fermenter) and the [Free Online Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fermentor): **fermenter**: any agent or substance, such as a bacterium, mold, yeast, or enzyme, that causes fermentation; or, *(also **fermentor**)* an apparatus that maintains optimal conditions for the growth of microorganisms, used in large-scale fermentation and in the commercial production of antibiotics and hormones.

So *fermenter* can mean either the enzyme or the fermentation apparatus, whereas *fermentor* can only be used to mean the apparatus.

Comment: @Joe:  I checked up on the Homebrewing site, and found while brewchez is right in proposing a _fermentor_ tag as a less ambiguous option than the current _fermenter_ tag, you are right in saying that _fermenter_ is not incorrect from a solely English-concerned standpoint.  That said, you homebrewers can decide for yourselves whether the current ambiguity in that tag poses enough of a problem to be worth changing.

Answer (score 4):

*Fermentor* is a container in which fermentation takes place; *fermenter* can be that container, or an organism that causes fermentation.

Answer (score -1):

The -er ending in a word usually designates a person who performs some sort of function related to a verb.  For example, someone who fishes is a fish-er.  Someone who performs carpentry is a carpent-er.  Someone who doctors is a doctor-er, but the extra -er isn't usually used.

The -or ending in a word usually designates a machine or piece of equipment associated with a verb.  For example, a machine that processes food is a food process-or.  A machine that calculates is a calculat-or.

So, when talking about the fermentation of something, the container the fermentation takes place in is a piece of equipment, or a ferment-or.  The person (or organism) doing the fermentation is the ferment-er.  The final judge of the fermentation is the drink-er:-)

Comment: Which verb stems get which suffixes to make agent nouns is primarily a matter of the etymological origin of the stem. A third such suffix is *-ist,* from the Greek -ίστης, though that does not mean it is only for Greek verb stems (e.g., *rapist,* from Latin *rapio).* The *-er* suffix is also used to form comparatives of adjectives.